# change the file type dynamically in 360 player

Tags: soundmanager2

Im using Sound manager with 360 player . I want to change the file type of a link if it does not support.How to make this?

Example:

```
< a href="sound.php?id=1" type="audio/mp3">Sound 1< / a >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it, but your sound file should be at the same type.

In case you want to change this dynamically, you should reload the sound the manager and the 360 player because they parse this link and read the file tybe at the initialization phase

Comment: I trying similar to html5 audio tag < audio controls > < source src="mp3_type_file_url" > < source src = "ogg_type_file" > </audio>